# Made error or did error?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Staff nurse made error in recording patient's name in a book. Or staff nurse did error in recording patient's name in a book.

Which one of these is correct?

Comment: Neither. Where are your articles (the, an, etc?)

Answer (score 2):

make and do are tricky for learners.

- make a mistake or make an error
- make a cake
- make dinner
- do work or do a translation
- do a task

Those are a few to get you started.

**The** staff nurse made **an** error when recording, etc.

Comment: This also has to do one's native language. My native language (Malay), for example, consistently uses 'melakukan kesalahan' (literally 'do mistakes'). I [negatively transfered](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_transfer) this feature when learning English.

Comment: @user178049 Not every language has two verbs for make. Some  only have one...French and Spanish only have one....:) No worries.

Answer (score 0):

*Make* means to create or cause.

> I'm going to make a cake.

> I'm going to make this car run again.

*Do* is used when you want to talk about an action but don't have a name for the action, or don't want to repeat the name for the action).  It's also used for emphasis.

> I'm not sure what to do. (unknown action)

> A: Who set this here?  B: Alice and Bob did. (B doesn't want to be repetitive by saying "set this here" again).

> I did talk to Mary. (emphasis)

If something is being created or caused, then that's your name for that action, and thus you should use *make*.

*Made an error in X* is very idiomatic in English.

Spanish uses *hacer* to mean both *do* and *make*, English uses separate words.